# how to check if an event was added to the log in a contract constructor

Tags: truffle, testing

when executing a transaction in truffle tests, the return value is the transaction receipt and one can check for the presence of a particular event in the logs.

this is not possible when the transaction is a contract creation as the returned value is not the transaction receipt but the contract instance.

how can I get to the transaction receipt after instantiating a new contract?

```
return UserDirectory.new(root.address, {from: newUser})
  .then(d => {
    /*I would like to get the list of events here*/
    dir = d
    return dir.brg()
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `truffle-assertions` package can easily help with this.
Once the package is installed you can run the following:

```js
// Import the package to your file
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');

// Deploy the contract
let testContract = await TestContract.new()

// Get the hash of the deployment transaction
let txHash = testContract.transactionHash

// Get the transaction result using truffleAssert
let result = await truffleAssert.createTransactionResult(testContract, txHash)

// Now look at the events using truffleAssert
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'TestEvent');
```

You'll find more information about the package here https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions

And you can install it as follows:
`npm install truffle-assertions`

Answer (score 2):

> this is not possible when the transaction is a contract creation as the returned value is not the transaction receipt but the contract instance.

One of the benefits of Truffle is that it hides away a lot of the complexity from the user, but don't let that fool you; whilst creating a contract is a special transaction (in that it has no to address), it is still a transaction and has a corresponding Transaction ID/Hash. [We can verify this by using Etherscan to find a contract creation transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5364a1a78cf70d33b161076a18e5d0561b2717973a36e1d51d325ea3c43273f7).

If you want to get hold of this, then you are going to have to get your hands a little dirty and do some of the heavy lifting that Truffle hides away from you: if you look at the [web3 documentation then you can find how to deploy a contract](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).

As per the documentation, you can see that after some work setting up the necessary code, a transaction hash for the transaction of creating a contract can be retrieved.

```
...
var myContractInstance = MyContract.new(param1, param2, {data: myContractCode, gas: 300000, from: mySenderAddress});
// The hash of the transaction, which created the contract
myContractInstance.transactionHash
```

I'm not entirely sure how this relates to the title question

> how to check if an event was added to the log in a contract contructor

I will add, that [the events API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) allows you to look for events in past blocks - as per the documentation you can specify the block to start looking from:

```
...
// watch for an event with {some: 'args'}
var myEvent = myContractInstance.MyEvent({some: 'args'}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
```

You may, therefore, be able to achieve this by

- 1: Finding out [the current block number](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock)
- 2: Deploying the contract with Truffle and waiting for it to be mined - as you are already doing
- 3: Call the event code specifying a block number in from equal to the block number in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using OpenZeppelin Test Helper [expectEvent.inConstruction](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#inconstruction).

*Contract*:

```csharp
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Test {
    address public owner;

    event ContractCreated();

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;

        emit ContractCreated();
    }
}
```

*truffle-test*:

```js
const { expectEvent } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

const TestContract = artifacts.require('Test');

contract('Test', function (accounts) {
    const [owner] = accounts;
    const txParams = { from: owner };

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.testContract = await TestContract.new(txParams);
    });

    describe('construction', function () {
        it('initial state', async function () {
            expect(await this.testContract.owner()).to.equal(owner);

            await expectEvent.inConstruction(this.testContract, 'ContractCreated');
        });
    });
});
```

---

*package.json*

```json
{
..
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.10"
  }
..
}
```

Comment: hi vladmir thanks for this. It seems to work only for a single event though. If multiple events are emitted the receipt would always be the one for the first event it seems